# Overloading functions with different return value c++

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, virtual-functions

I want to know if there is any way to overload functions with only different return type?
So, I have several classes derived from base class. All they have one method to return struct data. But each of them returns struct of different type (Module, Item, etc).
Is it possible to create a virtual method GetData() in base class and overload it only by return type? I guess I need to use templates. Unfortunately I don’t understand how to do so.